# alertify.alert doesnt work in mithril (m.request) response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mithril.js, alertify

i am working on a project where i am using [mithril.js](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/) and also using [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) in the response i want to alert some data it doesnt work and if the same alert i am using before m.request it works fine

```
        function send_data()
        {        
         m.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: url_root,
            config: xhrConfig
        }).then(
            function(response) {
             alertify.alert("test");
          });
     }
send_data();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying and pasting from the answer I gave you on [the Github issue you raised for Mithril](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/issues/793):

[Works for me using alertify 3.11](https://jsbin.com/qudupo/edit?html,js,output). v0.5rc1 can't even execute without breaking ('alertify is undefined'). What problem are you facing?